# iOS Facebook login stopped to work

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, native, single-sign-on

I have native facebook app in development for few months and login worked on ios and android.
Yesterday iOS login stopped to work. Android app is able to login.
I have not changed iOS code.

I was unable to login with Facebook Native client. I have uninstalled it and I still get same page on FB website. I am redirected to following page

http://m.facebook.com/home.php?_rdr

Have  someone get same problem?

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Facebook application ID. Mine was deleted and I've got the same problem as you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything on your end, Facebook might have chained something with their API.  Perhaps there is an issue with the OAuth or something.  Have you taken a look at Facebook's developer portal to see if they have changed anything recently?

Comment: yes. I checked facebook status and bugs. I have not seems such probelem. googling shows similar reports in 2011 but some my app and other apps work fine. I have no idea how to debug that problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to authenticate in a desktop browser using firebug or so and check all the http traffic and response to figure out what the problem could be